# Why does gcc use the size-aware delete operator by default when optimizing?

Tags: c++, gcc, new-operator, delete-operator

If I define my own `new` and `delete` operators as shown below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

void* operator new (size_t count)
{
    printf("Calling custom new!\n");
    return malloc(count);
}

void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{ printf("Called size unaware delete!\n");
  free(p);
}

int main()
{
    int *a = new int{1};
    delete a;
}
```

and compile using `gcc` version 12.1, with `-O2 -Wall` options specified, I get a `mismatched-new-delete` warning.  Looking at the compiled output, I see that the compiler uses the size-aware delete operator (signature `void operator delete(void *p, std::size_t sz);`) instead of the custom one I defined (see [compiler explorer output](https://godbolt.org/z/sMhWGKhdz) for details).

Other compilers such as `clang` use the delete operator I defined, and thus do not result in that mismatched operator warning.  Why does `gcc` use the size-aware version when optimizing?

Comment: FYI I don't think Clang supports sized delete by default, it needs `-fsized-deallocation`. The flag doesn't affect the behavior in this case though.

Comment: Despite what the assembly looks like, GCC seems to call your custom `delete`. The message from it is printed in your link.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:  Yes, the custom delete operator does get called eventually, but by virtue of the fact that the size-aware delete operator calls it, not by the compiled output calling it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References are to the post-C++20 draft (n4861). I am also assuming C++14 or later, which introduced size-aware deallocation functions.

For your particular example, the delete expression is required to call the size-aware `operator delete`, since the type to be destroyed is complete. So GCC is behaving correctly. (see [[expr.delete]/10.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.delete#10.5))

It is however not a problem that the size-aware one is chosen, because the default behavior of the global `operator delete(void*, size_t)` overload, if not replaced, is to just call the corresponding `operator delete(void*)`, so your custom implementation will still be used in the end. (see [[new.delete.single]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete.single#16))

There is however a recommendation in [[new.delete.single]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete.single#11) that a program which replaces the `operator delete` version without `size_t` parameter should also replace the one with the `size_t` parameter. A note clarifies that although currently the standard library supplied default behavior of the size-aware versions call the custom non-size-aware implementation anyway, that may change in future standard revisions.

Also, the compiler is allowed to elide both the call to `operator new` and `operator delete` in the given example to either provide storage in a different manner or more likely to just elide the whole body of `main` which has no other observable side effects. So it is possible that no `operator delete` is called at all.

So, to future-proof the code and avoid linter warnings add a replacement for the size-aware global overload as well

```
void operator delete(void *p, std::size_t) noexcept
{
    ::operator delete(p);
}
```

Also note that the standard requires the replacement of this overload to behave in such a way that it could always be replaced by a call to the size-unaware version without affecting memory allocation. (see [[new.delete.single]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete.single#15))

---

Although required since C++14, Clang doesn't seem to enable size-aware deallocation functions yet by default. You need to add the `-fsized-deallocation` flag to enable them.

Some discussion of a patch enabling it by default seems to be going on [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D112921).

---

Also note that your implementation of `operator new` is broken. The throwing version of `operator new` is not allowed to return a null pointer. So you must check the return value of `malloc` and throw `std::bad_alloc` if it is null.

Comment: Also be aware that the compiler can merge multiple calls to new if it can observe the matching delete. `int *a = new int{1}; int *b = new int{2}; ... delete b; delete a;` can allocate 8 byte once and delete only once.

Comment: Thanks.  I was unaware of the recommendation to define both.  I was going by the guidelines from cppreference that suggest only the size-unaware version is required (see the global replacements section here:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

Comment: @Billy The note has been added to the standard draft over 9 years ago. I have not checked whether any work towards the suggested future direction happened, but maybe it has become less likely that the behavior will change, so that it might not be all that significant. For C++20 and below (and also C++23 as far as I can tell) at least, replacing the one without `size_t` parameter _is_ sufficient.